# *ngFor Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.'

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been using NGFor for a long time, but it seems that suddenly in this new application I am getting

> Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.'

When looking it up online it is showing older version of Angular, which is odd.  Likewise It is telling me to add BrowserModule in the imports which is generally a normal thing.  I currently am working on a App with Routing, so the App uses the RouterModule to fetch the right page.  In the App module, i have it as an import, along with BrowserModule.

**EDIT** I ended up doing a *ngFor loop in my base page, so it seems to work. I am thinking the issue happens from the concept of the route?  I access it in my RouterModule by:

`{path: 'industry/manufacturing', component: ManufacturingComponent},`

Is accessing by route requiring me to add CommonModule to the RouterModule?

My Angular specs are:

```
Angular CLI: 10.0.8
Node: 14.12.0
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 10.0.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.1000.8
@angular-devkit/core              10.0.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        10.0.8
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      10.0.8
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  10.0.8
@schematics/angular               10.0.8
@schematics/update                0.1000.8
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.9.7
webpack                           4.43.0
```

```
<div *ngFor="let mat of materials">
  {{mat.name}}: {{mat.quantity}}
</div>
```

where in the ts code i define it as:

`materials = [{"name": "foo", "quantity": 5}];`

My app.module looks like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ]
})
```

AppRoutingModule also is just a simple:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: MainComponent},
  {path: 'industry/manufacturing', component: ManufacturingComponent},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am not sure what is going on that is out of the ordinary here.

Comment: it seems like angular is not running on that page. try taking out the *ngFor and just see if {{materials}} shows anything. check the console for other errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing an import of `CommonModule` In your imports, unless its declared some where else that I cant see.
Edit: Your app module has BrowserModule which includes it, but it doesnt know about your components, Either add `CommonModule` to your `RoutingModule` (not recommended, its not the router job to handle who has what), or declare the components in your `AppModule` to let him know which components uses his imports.
Please refer to
https://stackblitz.com/angular/qypdxgpopxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.module.ts
for a wide example of routing and modules

Comment: I added an edit.  I was curious.  ngFor works on my other pages, but when accessing it through my routerModule is causes it issue. I was thinking that maybe I needed to dd the CommonModule, and attempted to add that there.  That failed to work, but i am not sure what is going on.

Comment: Where should this be at?  I tried to add it as a part of the RouterModule, but i only have an app.module, so i dont know where else this would need to be instantiated?

Comment: Sorry was a bit late where I am, You should commonly put it in the most shared module you have, if your main module is AppModule, add it there since you will probably need it to be user in many places around your app.
In your app you have BrowserModule (https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/BrowserModule) which is why it works in your main page.
Try either adding the commonModule in your routing module (not recommended since its not its real use), or let the AppModule know which components it affects (manufacturingComponent to AppModule declarations)

Comment: Also, a nice example if you want, https://stackblitz.com/angular/qypdxgpopxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.module.ts
Its a bit big if you are just starting with angular but it has pretty big routing example and splitting modules.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps and see.

1. Import CommonsModule
2. Re run ng serve
3. Perform an npm install
4. Try going to the .ts file of the Template you're placing the *ngFor and re save the .ts file. I find this solves a lot of my template related issues